# Submodules and $T$-invariant subspaces.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, invariant-subspace, polynomial-rings

My professor wrote this on the board:

*Claim*: there is a bijection between submodules and $T$-invariant subspaces {$T(w) \subset W$}.

*Proof:*

If $W \subset V$ is $T$-invariant, then $f(X).w = f(T)(w) \in W.$ so $W$ is a submodule.
Conversely, let $W \subset V$ be a submodule, then for $w \in W,$ $X.w = T(w) \in W$ and hence $W$ is $T$-invariant.

---

Before that she wrote this:

Let $k$ be a field, $V$ a $k-$ vector space, $n = \dim_kV < \infty.$$R = k[x], T \in L(V)=$ linear operators on $V.$

$T$ has minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial in $R.$

$V$ has the structure of an $R$-module, a structure induced by $T.$

$$\varphi : R \rightarrow \operatorname{End_k(V)} = L(V)$$
$$1 \mapsto I$$
$$X \mapsto T$$

So $\varphi(f(X)) = f(T)$

Scalar multiplication in $V$ is $f(X).v = f(T)(v).$ then she asked what are the submodules of $V$ and she began to prove the above claim.

But I do not understand the following:

1- Why she defined $\varphi$ like that?

2- why the scalar multiplication in $V$ looks like that?

3- I do not understand at all how the forward direction proves that it is a submodule, why we are applying $f(X)$ to $w$ to prove this?

4- why in the backward direction we are applying $X$ to $w$?

could anyone help me understand all these points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $k[X]$ is a free $k$-algebra on one generator and it has the universal property that $k$-algebra homomorphisms from $k[X]$ into any $k$-algebra is defined by the choice of the image of the indeterminate $X$. Also note that $\operatorname{End}_k(V)$ is a $k$-algebra, in which multiplication is simply the composition of endomorphisms.
2. Scalar multiplication by a polynomial results from considering a homomorphism  from $k[X]$ into $\operatorname{End}_k(V)$, i.e. from the choice of an endomorphism $T$ associated to $X$. If you're interested in the properties of a given endomorphism, you'll choose for the image of $X$ this endomorphism.
3. We actually apply $f(T)$ to a vector in $V$ because by definition, scalar multiplication by the polynomial $f(X)$ consists in applying the endomorphism $f(T)$ to this vector.
4. I don't understand what you call the backwards direction is.

Comment: where are the conditions for submodule varified i.e. closure under addition and  multiplication?

Comment: I meant by the backward direction when she said conversely in the proof.

Comment: I see. It is simply that scalar multiplication as a $k[X]$-module is defined by the multiplication by $X$ (multiplication by elements of $k$ are the usual multiplication as a subspace), so it is a $k[X]$ submodule if & only if it is stable by multiplication by $X$, i.e. if & only if it is a $T$-invariant subspace.

Comment: and where is closure under addition in the submodule proof ?

Comment: That is because in commutative algebra, ring or algebra homomorphisms map the unit element of the domain onto the unit element of the codomain, and the identity endomorphism is the unit element for composition of endomorphisms. For addition, we have subspaces, so they're closed under addition by definition.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for deleting the comment.

Comment: Don't be sorry. It's always a pleasure to help!

Comment: what about my third comment from below?

Comment: Do you mean about closure under addition?

Comment: yes{}{}}{}}{}{} !

Comment: I had the time to add something about that in my third comment above.

Comment: But I did not understand how what you said speaks about closure under addition :(

Comment: It's subspaces (as $k$-vector spaces) that we deal with. By definition, they're closed under addition.